# Difference between average position of electron and average separation between proton and electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, vectors, orbitals, distance

I'm not sure to understand what is the difference between those 2 terms in the hydrogen atom.

The average position $\langle \hat{\bf r} \rangle$ is written $\langle \Psi^{*}|\hat {\bf r}|\Psi \rangle$, then for me the average separation which is the radius should be written the same.

$\Psi(r,\theta,\phi) = R_{nl}(r)Y^m_l(\theta.\phi)$

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question regarding what is $\Psi$

Comment: Is there a reason that you have a "hat" (the $\hat{}$ symbol) over the first $r$ and not the second $r$? I mean, is your hat supposed to indicate an operator? Or a unit vector?

Comment: If these are the solutions to Schrodinger equation for a hydrogen atom, do you realise that the position coordinate in it is the difference coordinate, which is essentially the separation distance between electron and proton. Any two body problem in physics is solved by splitting the equations of motion for centre of mass and separation coordinates. In case of H-atom, the centre of mass doesn't experience any potential, only separation distance has a coulomb interaction leading to this kind of a solution.

Comment: Then what will be the average position of the electron. I don't figure it out. I thought what I wrote was the average position of the electron. I'm still completely confuse. Looking on google to find an answer I saw both terms using differently.

Answer (score 1):

The usual meaning of "position" in physics is a vector with three components that can be positive or negative. The usual meaning of "distance" or "separation" is a scalar that is always positive.

This doesn't have to do with quantum mechanics. A planet orbiting a star in a circle with radius $10^8 \text{ km}$. The planet is always the same distance from the star, $10^8 \text{ km}$, but its position is always changing. Sometimes its position is $(10^8,0)$, sometimes it's $(-10^8,0)$, and sometimes it's $(0,10^8)$.

If you average the distance of the planet from the star as it goes around, you'll get $10^8 \text{ km}$, but if you average the position you'll get $(10^8,0)+(-10^8,0)+\dots = (0,0)$.

The same is true for the electron. There are three position operators for the electron that we could call $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$. There is also a distance operator that we could call $\hat{r}$ that is different from the three position operators. These operators do not all have the same expectation values.

Comment: If I understood. In spherical coordinates. The position depends of $r,\theta,\phi$ and the radius depends of $r$. For example, [here](http://www.astro.uvic.ca/~jwillis/teaching/phys215/phys215_lecture6.pdf) P.7 and 8 they seems to mix average position and average radius. Maybe this is just me, but I don't follow Griffith as well when he talks about average position and average radius.